# Modal Lightbox Gallery and Carousel Slider incompatible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

It seems quite challenging to add both the Bootstrap [Carousel Slider](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/ZbGwqe) and 
 [Lightbox Gallery](https://codepen.io/webcane/pen/lHGJf) in a single page without significant issues.

**Problem:** When clicking on the **lightbox image gallery** it opens up the picture gallery and at the same time the **Carousel slider** image gets hijacked by the gallery images. The culprit seems to be either the classes: **.item**, **img**, or **.inner-carousel**

> **Is it possible to add both modal lighbox and carousel slider to a single page without any issues?**

To recreate the issue: Click on the image gallery, the modal will pop up, close the window, and now the carousel slider has been replaced by the gallery images. http://jsfiddle.net/2aasoyej/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Bootstrap 3 lightbox hidden gallery using modal</h1>
        <hr>

    <div class="row">

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 1" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-1" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/ccc/969696&amp;text=0xD10x810xD00xB50xD10x800xD10x8B0xD00xB9">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 2" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-2" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/2255EE/969696&amp;text=0xD10x810xD00xB80xD00xBD0xD00xB80xD00xB9">
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a title="Image 3" href="#"> 
                        <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" id="image-3" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/449955/FFF&amp;text=0xD00xB70xD00xB50xD00xBB0xD00xB50xD00xBD0xD10x8B0xD00xB9">
                    </a>
                </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

  </div>
</div>

    <div class="hidden" id="img-repo">

        <!-- #image-1 -->
        <div class="item" id="image-1">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 11" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/ccc/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-1">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 12" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/ccc/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-1">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 13" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/ccc/969696">
        </div>

        <!-- #image-2 -->
        <div class="item" id="image-2">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 21" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/2255EE/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-2">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 21" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/2255EE/969696">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-2">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 23" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/2255EE/969696">
        </div>   

        <!-- #image-3-->
        <div class="item" id="image-3">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 31" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x350/449955/FFF">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-3">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 32" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/449955/FFF">
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="image-3">
            <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" title="Image 33" src="http://dummyimage.com/300x300/449955/FFF">
        </div>        

    </div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-gallery" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="modal-carousel" class="carousel">

            <div class="carousel-inner">           
            </div>

            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modal-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>

          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





        <!-- Header Carousel -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">

                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One');">    
                <center>
                <div class="carousel-title">
                    <h1>Certified General Contractor</h1>
                </div>

                </center>
                </div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">

                    <h2>For all your South Florida construction needs</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two');">
                        <center>
                <div class="carousel-title">
                    <h1>Commercial Contruction</h1>
                </div>

                </center>
                    </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Build with a company you can trust</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three');">

                    <center>
                <div class="carousel-title">
                    <h1>Home Renovation</h1>
                </div>

                </center>
            </div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h2>Remodel your home with the best in the field</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev" style="font-size:70px;"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next" style="font-size:70px;"></span>
        </a>
```

**JS:**

```
var $item = $('.carousel .item'); 
var $wHeight = $(window).height();
$item.eq(0).addClass('active');
$item.height($wHeight); 
$item.addClass('full-screen');

$('.carousel img').each(function() {
  var $src = $(this).attr('src');
  var $color = $(this).attr('data-color');
  $(this).parent().css({
    'background-image' : 'url(' + $src + ')',
    'background-color' : $color
  });
  $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function (){
  $wHeight = $(window).height();
  $item.height($wHeight);
});

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 6000,
  pause: "false"
});
```

Comment: The interesting part of the javascript code is missing here, but can be found in the fiddle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the *$(".row .thumbnail").click(function()* you are querying *$('.carousel-inner')* which infact matches both carousels' .carousel-inner

```
$(".row .thumbnail").click(function(){
    var content = $(".carousel-inner");
```

..and then you call *content.empty()* and *content.append(repoCopy)*. This does affect both carousels, too, of course.

You need to be more precise here:

```
$(".row .thumbnail").click(function(){
    var content = $("#modal-carousel .carousel-inner");
```

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2aasoyej/1/

Udated fiddle that properly disables the interval for the modal carousel, as noted in comments below: http://jsfiddle.net/2aasoyej/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however you just created another issue. Check out the updated fiddle you provided, when you click on the image it should pop up in Gallery mode, but instead it pops up in Carousel mode. The image gallery now transformed into a slideshow.

Comment: Your original fiddle does exactly the same here, which is to be expected as you just wrap the "gallery" carousel in a modal window. How would you expect it to look like exactly?

Comment: The Carousel should automatically play a slideshow of pictures, but the image gallery should open up a modal image which you can scroll through, but won't play automatically (i.e. not a slideshow like the carousel)

Comment: Ah, now I got it. I updated the fiddle above. The solution is to use the id rather than the .carousel class for the #myCarousel carousel, too.

Comment: Thank you!  I commend you on your solution it's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. :)